# How to divide by 12 quickly?

Tags: divisibility, natural-numbers

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ be divisible by 12 and $n/12<100$. Is there a way of computing $n/12$ rather quickly using mental arithmetic (e.g. for 972/12, 1044/12, etc.)?

For example, the number 11 seems to have a nice property. When we consider $836/11=d$ then
770<836, but 880>836, so the first digit of $d$ must be 7. And since the last digit of $836$ is $6$, so is the last digit of $d$. This gives us $d=76$.
Or consider $693/11=d$. Then $660<693$ (and 770>693), so the first digit of $d$ must be $6$ and the second is $3$ since this is the last digit of $693$. This gives us $d=63$.

Now, is there another (possibly similar) approach for dividing by 12 (or even 13, 14, etc.)? But I am mostly interested in a "trick" for the number 12 (just using mental arithmetic).

Comment: If I want to divide mentally by $12$, I just divide by $2,2$, and $3$ (or sometimes by $4$ and $3$) in whatever order seems easiest.

Comment: As $100=8\cdot12+4,1000=83\cdot12+4$

For any four digit number $$1000a+100b+10c+d=(83\cdot12+4)a+(8\cdot12+4)b+10c+d=12(83a+8b)+4a+4b+10c+d$$  Then, handle $4a+4b+10c+d$ separately

Comment: Perhaps you could learn the duodecimal system :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can memorize multiples of $12$ that are less than $100$. Then if $n/12=10a+b$ you can guess $a$ quite fast. And there are two options for $b$. Now if $n=100a+(2a+b)10+2b$ then you can decide about $b$ by comparing $2a+b$ and the second least significant digit of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide by $10$ by shifting the decimal point, then subtract $1/6$ and round.  So for example $1044/10=104.4, 1/6$ of $104.4$ is about $17, 104.4-17=87.4$

Comment: For dividing by six, could first divide by two and then divide that number by three. Example: 300/10 = 30 → 30/2 = 15 → 15/3 = 5. In the end, 300/12 = 30-5 = 25.

Answer (score 0):

When I were a lad, there were twelve pennies to a shilling, and we all had to learn our tables up to $12 \times 12$. So I can do these in my head just by the usual process of short division.